# Mysql Inner query gives all column names of outer query selected table name

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql 5.6.10 , I want a query which has Outer query "table name" to be used in Inner Query  to get all the columns of the "Table"(of Outer Queries) ,

I have two tables in a DB say **test**

First Table **tbl_1**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_1` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `new_loc_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_loc_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Second Table **tbl_2**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_2` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have composed something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('|QUERY|Select * from  test.',tbl.table_name,'|\n' ,
'|COLUMN|',(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ' | ') FROM information_schema.COLUMNS clm
WHERE table_schema = 'test' 
AND tbl.table_name = clm.table_name),'|\n'
) AS ddl
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.txt'
FROM information_schema.TABLES tbl
WHERE tbl.table_schema = 'test'
AND tbl.table_type = 'base table';
```

OutPut of the Query is error:

```
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'tbl.table_name' in 'where clause'
```

What I'm expecting is :

```
|QUERY|Select * from  test.tbl_1|
|COLUMN|id | log_id | new_loc_id | old_loc_id | msg | id | name | loc_id | parent_id|

|QUERY|Select * from  test.tbl_2|
|COLUMN|id | name| loc_id| parent_id|
```

Comment: WHERE table_schema = 'test' 
AND AND tbl.table_name = clm.table_name : You are using two times AND & you are using alias tbl inside the bracket which is crreated outside the bracket

Comment: @Ahmad : Sorry for typo

Answer (score 1):

The query is perfect.
except the AND AND.
WHERE table_schema = 'test' AND AND